# Programmatically remove linked files from the project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I'm developing plugin for Eclipse. This plugin nothing else but the wizard to allows user to create its own file format with inbuilt jar files inside. All the JARs inside are linked resources for the project.
To clean the project I need to remove all the linked JARs from the project programmatically.
Are there any suggestions how to do that?

- how to search files by mask?
- how to know that this is linked file?
- and how to remove linked resource?