# Eclipse project - add linked resources programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, nodeclipse, eclipse-project-file

An example of `.project` contains

```
<linkedResources>
    <link>
        <name>node_lib</name>
        <type>2</type>
        <location>E:/Nodejs/node-v0.10.22/node-v0.10.22/lib</location>
    </link>
</linkedResources>
```

How to add linked resources programmatically?

`org.eclipse.core.resources.IProjectDescription` does not have related methods

[image: IProjectDescription]

So this Q mentions `getLinks()` for `IProject`  ([JavaDoc](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IProject.html) has no)
[Eclipse Add marker for linked resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475038/eclipse-add-marker-for-linked-resources)

Related to:
[Programmatically remove linked files from the project in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290641/programmatically-remove-linked-files-from-the-project-in-eclipse)

UPDATED:
Solved with help of both answers, as they brought understanding of Eclipse terminology (what is what)

Code

```
   IFolder link = project.getFolder("Link");
   IPath location = new Path("TEMP/folder");
   if (workspace.validateLinkLocation(location).isOK()) {
      link.createLink(location, IResource.NONE, null);
   } else {
      //invalid location, throw an exception or warn user
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your linked questions actually refers to [example code](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/resInt_linked.htm) using the [`createLink`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IFolder.html) method of `IFolder`.

Answer (score 1):

You use the `createLink` methods of `IFile` and `IFolder` to create linked resources.

For a file you do two steps:

```
// Get IFile for file
IFile newFile = project.getFile(workspacePath);

// Create the link
newFile.createLink(actualPath, flags, monitor);
```

and much the same for a folder:

```
IFolder newFolder = project.getFolder(workspacePath);

newFolder.createLink(actualPath, flags, monitor);
```